# How can I dynamically create Syncfusion Ui's KanbanComponent and set Kanban Component header in ReactJS using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syncfusion

How to create syncfution Ui's KanbanComponent Dynamically in React js and also how to set Kanban Component header Dynamically?

```
<ColumnsDirective>
                                        <ColumnDirective headerText="Active" keyField="Active" allowToggle={true} template={this.columnTemplate} />
                                        <ColumnDirective headerText="Work In Progress" keyField="workInProgress" allowToggle={true} template={this.columnTemplate} />
                                        <ColumnDirective headerText="Approved" keyField="Approved" allowToggle={true} template={this.columnTemplate} />
                                        <ColumnDirective headerText="Closed" keyField="Closed" allowToggle={true} template={this.columnTemplate} />
                                        <ColumnDirective headerText="Archive" keyField="Archive" allowToggle={true} template={this.columnTemplate} />
                                    </ColumnsDirective>
```

```
 <KanbanComponent
                   dialogOpen={this.dialogOpen.bind(this)}
                                    id="kanban"
                                    cssClass="kanban-overview"
                                    keyField="T_Status"
                                    dataSource={this.getFilteredData()}
                                    dragStop={(data: any) => {
                                        this.props.onTasksStatusChanged(data);
                                    }}
                                    enableTooltip={true}
                                    swimlaneSettings={{ keyField: "P_ProjectEngineer", allowDragAndDrop: true }}
                                    cardSettings={{
                                        headerField: "T_Title",
                                        template: this.renderCardTemplate.bind(this),
                                        selectionType: "Multiple"
                                    }}
                                    //dialogSettings={{ fields: fields as any }}
                                    cardRendered={(props: any) => this.cardRenderer(props)}>
                                     <ColumnsDirective>
                                        {this.props.columnName.map((e: any) => {
                                            return <ColumnDirective headerText={e} keyField={e} allowToggle={true} template={this.columnTemplate} />
                                        })}
                                    </ColumnsDirective>
                                </KanbanComponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set Kanban component header dynamically, you can use the columns property of the Kanban. Check the code and sample below,

Code snippet:

```
 <KanbanComponent
        id="kanban"
        cssClass="kanban-overview"
        keyField="Status"
        dataSource={data}
        enableTooltip={true}
        swimlaneSettings={{ keyField: 'Assignee' }}
        cardSettings={{
          headerField: 'Title',
          template: cardTemplate.bind(this),
          selectionType: 'Multiple',
        }}
        dialogSettings={{ fields: fields }}
        cardRendered={cardRendered.bind(this)}
        columns={columns}
      >         
        
      </KanbanComponent>

let columns= [
{
  headerText: 'To Do',
  keyField: 'Open',
  allowToggle: true,
},
{
  headerText: 'In Progress',
  keyField: 'InProgress',
  allowToggle: true,
},
{
  headerText: 'In Review',
  keyField: 'Review',
  allowToggle: true,
},
{
  headerText: 'Done',
  keyField: 'Close',
  allowToggle: true,
},
```

],

**Sample**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pjv7rd?file=index.js

**API Link**: https://helpej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/kanban#columns

Regards,

Vinitha